# Permission denied while calling GCP App engine REST API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to call GCP App Engine REST API- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps/get from API explorer as well as postman . This gives http code 403 . I am able to deploy service from my local using cloud sdk with same user account. Not sure why only REST API is not working. Any body else faced this issue.

Request - GET [https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/test?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]](https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/test?key=%5BYOUR_API_KEY%5D) HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
Response-
{
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "The caller does not have permission",
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
}

roles added to my principle-
App Engine Admin,
App Engine Code Viewer,
App Engine Deployer,
App Engine Service Admin,
App Engine Viewer,
Owner

Comment: What did you use in the appsid field? Did you put your project ID? try project ID and let us know.

Comment: Did you add the access token in the authorization-bearer header?

Comment: @danyL it worked with projectId as appsId Thanks

Comment: np ill put it an answer for the benefit of the community

Answer (score 0):

It should work with project ID